Estimation of evolutionary time to form DNA
It is often said that life formed on Earth randomly. Hence, the appearance of DNA molecule was the result of a random process. Can scientist estimate the time needed to form DNA molecule from just basic organic molecules, assuming conditions that were available at the born of life? Is there such an estimate? The age of the Earth is 4.5 billion years. How does that number compare to the time needed to form DNA?

Welcome wawa. It is often said that the Earth is flat, but that doesn't represent scientific models. Please take our [tour] and refer to the [help] particularly the [ask] section. You should then do some background reading around the topic and ask a biology question relating to how the science of biology views these things (based on available evidence). We also ask that you show your prior research into the topic, including references to credible source material (i.e. scientific journals, textbooks or at a bare minimum Wikipedia).

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Right, this is a hot topic in general, but not in the context of the question, i.e. time. The origin of life can be estimated using molecular clocks but the error range makes the calculation unworkable (in my opinion). The second problem is you've got to know the mechanism and when that occurred in the geology of earth.The mechanism, particularly in terms of respiration biochemistry is currently thought to be around hydrothermal vents and respiration via H2S, i.e  anaerobic respiration.

The term "life formed randomly" might be controversial, because even at the earliest stage of life selection would have kicked in; ultimately that random bit of DNA had to code for itself.
